# $B(l^2)$ is not postliminal. Why?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

A $C^*$-algebra is postliminal if $\pi(A)\supset \mathcal K(H)$ for any irreducible representation $(\pi, H)$, where $\mathcal K$ denotes the compact operator algebra on $H$.

$B(l^2)$ is not postliminal.

Since $\pi(A)x$ is separable and invariant, $H$ is separable. Therefore $\pi$ is an homomorphism from $B(l^2)$ to some subalgebra of $B(l^2)$.

Assume $\pi(A)\not\supset \mathcal K$, then $\pi(A)\cap \mathcal K$ must be $0$ (because of irreducibility). However, let $p$ be a minimal projection, $\pi(p)$ is a projection. Assume the range of $\pi(p)$ contains at least $2$ nonzero diagonal vectors, say, $x,y$, again by irreducibility, there is some $\pi(a)\in \pi(A)$ such that $\pi(a)x=x$ and $\pi(a)y=0$. $pap=kp$ in $A$, however, $\pi(p)\pi(a)\pi(p)\neq kp$ since $\pi(p)\pi(a)\pi(p)x=x$ and $\pi(p)\pi(a)\pi(p)y=0$, which is a contradiction.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The restriction on $\pi(A)x$ is a subrepresentation so $\pi(A)x$ is dense in $H$. Therefore $H$ is separable. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that $\pi(p)\ne0$. If you consider $\pi$ the quotient map onto the Calkin algebra (and you compose with an irrep of the Calkin algebra) you get an irreducible representation that is zero on the compacts of $\ell^2$; as the image does not contain minimal projections, it cannot contain the compacts of $H$.

Comment: But calkin algebra isn't separable since it contains uncountably many diagonal projections. How can an irreducible representation be nonseparable?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is showing that $B(l^2)$ is not postliminal but I also wonder where am I wrong.

Comment: Where you assume that $\pi(p)\ne0$.

Comment: Yes it is one of the mistakes and I get you. But you say there is an irreducible representation onto the Calkin algebra, which seems impossible to me. Fix a dense countable set $\mathcal F$ of $A$, then $\pi(\mathcal F)x$ is dense in $\pi(A)x$ since $\pi$ is contractive. Therefore $\pi(A)x$ is separable. But Calkin algebra contains uncountably many diagonal projections so it has no separable representation. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: $B(\ell^2)$ is not separable.

Comment: It is not? Then I have made a great mistake...

Comment: It is separable as a von Neumann algebra, but not as a C$^*$-algebra. It is trivial to see, as it contains a copy of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ in the diagonal. And that's why the Calkin is non-separable.